# Get the list of Object References in EntityFramework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using EF code first in my asp.net application

I have one entity class called DayType

```
public class DayType : LookUpCommonField
{
  [Key]
    public int DayTypeId { get; set; }
    public Guid DayTypeGuid { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Colour { get; set; }
    public string ColorCode { get; set; }
    public bool IsFullShiftOt { get; set; }

    public bool IsAllowedAsHoliday { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Holiday> Holiday { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ShiftOvertimeCondition> ShiftOvertimeConditions { get; set; }
}
```

LookupCommonField class contains

```
public class LookUpCommonField
    {
        public int Status { get; set; }
        public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public int? EditedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EditedOn { get; set; }
        public int? LocationId { get; set; }
    }
```

`Status` is maintained to identify whether the record is Active or Deleted.
All the tables in the database contains this `Status` field, and i do not physically delete my records.

but in `DayType` I want to physically delete the record, and i want to track what are the tables that the `DayTypeId` is referenced.
Is there any possible way in `EntityFramework` to achieve this?

I'm doing this for the time being.

```
var dayType = myDb.DayType.FirstOrDefault(x => x.DayTypeGuid == dayTypeGuid);

            string sqlCommand = string.Format("SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) + '.' + t.name AS 'Table Name' FROM sys.tables t INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id WHERE c.name like '%{0}Id%' ORDER BY 'Table Name' ", "DayType");
            var tables = myDb.Database.SqlQuery<string>(sqlCommand).ToList();
            int? count = 0;
            var isSuccess = false;

            foreach (var table in tables.Where(t => t.ToString() != "TimeAttendance.DayType"))
            {
                var searchCount = myDb.Database.SqlQuery<int?>(string.Format("SELECT count({0}Id)  FROM {1} WHERE {2}Id={3} and Status=1", "DayType", table, "DayType", dayType.DayTypeId)).FirstOrDefault();

                if (searchCount != null && Convert.ToInt32(searchCount) > 0)
                {
                    count += searchCount;
                }

            }

if(count ==0)
{
  myDB.DayType.Remove(dayType);
  myDB.SaveChanges();
  isSuccess= true;
 }
```

I want to achieve this using EntityFramework. (Without using direct SQL Queries)

--Edited--
Thank you all for looking in to the question. I was able to find an alternative solution to get the set of relationships for a given table.

```
    var objToCheck = myDB.DayType.FirstOrDefault(w=>w.DayTypeId==entityId);
        var relatedEntities = ((System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter)myDB).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetRelationshipManager(objToCheck).GetAllRelatedEnds().ToList();
foreach(IRelatedEnd relatedEnd in relatedEntities.ToList())
{
     // I want to check every entry in the related end to check the Status
     // Does any body has a suggession?
}
```

Comment: When you say "i want to track what are the tables that the DayTypeId is referenced", what do you mean? What are you trying to achieve by knowing its references? Are you wanting to delete all referenced records as well? If so you should check out Cascade Delete

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. Actually what i want to do is, I want to delete a perticualr DayType if there are no other active records (Status==1) in anywhere in the database that DayTypeId is referenced